# Do git commits ever get deleted after resetting the branch?

Tags: git

Let's say I only have master branch, and I have made some commits: commit 1, 2 and 3.

If I do a `git reset --hard` to commit 2, then push and keep on committing code. Will commit 3 stay in the git database forever or will be deleted eventually?

Comment: It will be deleted...eventually.  In the interim period, if you ever accidentally delete a branch, you may find the deleted commits in the `git reflog`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They live until `git gc` cleans them up, as [WofWca said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54799175/1256452), but precisely when that occurs can be a bit difficult to pin down.

Some commands run `git gc --auto` for you automatically.  These days, that includes `git commit`: `git commit` was always supposed to run this, but the code was accidentally dropped in a very early version of Git—Git 1.5.4—and not restored until 2.17.  But `git gc --auto` does nothing if, in its assessment, there's no reason to run yet, and that's most of the times it's run.<sup>1</sup>  Then, when `git gc` decides it *should* run, or when you run `git gc` without `--auto` yourself to run it right away, even then it may not delete these commits *yet*.

What keeps the commit alive?  Well, the answer is complicated:

1. Each reference—and branch names are references whose full name starts with `refs/heads/`—may have a *reflog*.  The reflog stores *reflog entries*, which are time-stamped records that say, in effect, this reference was set to hash ID *H* at date *D*.  This allows Git to recover the state of a branch (or any other reference) as of a specific time, given in either absolute or relative terms, as long as the reflog entries near that time have not yet expired.

   These reflog entries *do* expire, though, except for `refs/stash`, which by default never has its reflog entries expired.  Git removes any expired entries, leaving only the unexpired ones in the log.  The expiration period for each entry is configurable.  The default is either 30 or 90 days, as set by `gc.reflogExpire` and `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable`.  Which one applies?  Well, that's tricky: it depends on the notion of *reachability*.  To get a good thorough idea of what reachability means, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

   In this particular case we're interested in whether the hash ID stored in the reflog entry is reachable from the hash ID stored in the reference itself.  That is, given a name like `refs/heads/master`, we check `master@{1}` to see if that's an ancestor of `master` itself.  If so, that reflog entry *is* reachable (from the current `master`).  If not, that reflog entry is *not* reachable (from the current `master`).  That in turn picks which of the two `gc.reflogExpire` variables should be used.  (If the branch has a custom setting through `gc.<pattern>.reflogExpire` and/or `gc.<pattern>.reflogExpireUnreachble`, that's used instead, of course.  The documentation calls this a *pattern* and appears to use the file name pattern matching code, the same as `.gitattributes` for instance.)

   Having picked an expiry variable, Git then compares the reflog's timestamp against the implied expiration date.  If the reflog entry has been expired, it gets removed.

   If the reflog entry remains, it protects the object whose hash ID the reflog contains, *and* all objects that are reachable from that object.  For commit objects, this means the commit itself is protected, and so are all of its ancestors, and its and their snapshots.

   The short version of this is that by default, reflog entries remain for at least 30 days.  Reflog entries that are ancestors of the current branch tip remain for at least 90 days.  After this kind of `git reset`, the entry is *not* an ancestor of the branch tip, so the 30 day rule applies.
2. If step 1 does not preserve the internal object directly, there's also a reflog for `HEAD` itself, which may preserve the object directly.  And of course, either of these may preserve the object *indirectly*, through the reachability rules.
3. If neither steps 1 nor 2 preserve the object, directly or indirectly, it may still not be removed yet: *all* objects get a grace period, which defaults to 14 days and is configurable as `gc.pruneExpire`.  This grace period prevents a `git gc --auto` running in the background from deleting an object that's being created by some active Git command.  For instance, `git commit` may be running `git write-tree`, and `git write-tree` is busy spinning off tree objects based on the index contents.  Once `git write-tree` is finished, `git commit` runs `git commit-tree` to create the commit object itself.

   All of these are built into `git commit`, but still, they all create loose objects, none of which is as-yet reachable from *any* reference, so all of these *would* be eligible for garbage collection.  But the 14 day grace period means that `git commit` can, now that has written out some tree objects and a new commit object, finish the commit by making the branch name point to the commit, and adding the reflog entry to the branch's reflog.  As long as `git commit` manages to accomplish all of this within two weeks, Git is OK.  If your computer is too slow to finish a `git commit` in two weeks, well, that's pretty bad, in more ways than one.

So, this gives you the set of rules by which commits are preserved, or not.  On top of that, remember that *bare* repositories (as stored on servers) usually have reflogs disabled, and rarely deal with loose objects at all—objects that arrive at servers are normally brought in as a *thin pack*, which the server "fattens up" and then typically repacks soon anyway.  So servers tend to GC their objects a lot sooner than normal, non-bare repositories.

---

<sup>1</sup>To decide whether it's time to do something, `git gc --auto` executes these steps:

1. Count the number of *pack* files, excluding those marked "keep".  If this exceeds the threshold, it's time for a gc that includes repacking.
2. If step 1 doesn't fire, count the number of *loose objects* in the `objects/17` directory.  (The 17 here is an arbitrary choice and is hardcoded.  You would have to ask Linus or someone why 17.  The more obvious choice is 42, or perhaps 2a, since these are hexadecimal. :-) )  If this exceeds the threshold, it's time for a gc that builds one new pack.
3. If either step 1 or 2 didn't fire, don't do a GC.  Otherwise, run the `pre-auto-gc` hook to give it a chance to abort the GC.  If the hook does not exist, or exits with a successful, i.e., zero, status, go ahead and perform the GC.

The two thresholds in steps 1 and 2 are controlled by `gc.autopacklimit`, which defaults to 50, and `gc.auto`, which defaults to 6700.  You can configure either or both of these with `git config`.  If you set `gc.auto` to zero or negative, this inhibits both types of auto-gc, regardless of what you set `gc.autopacklimit` to.

The number you configure in `gc.autopacklimit` is divided by 256 with fractional part rounded up, so the default 6700 produces 27 (6700 / 256 being 26.171875).  The reason for dividing by 256 is that the loose objects are scattered throughout 256 subdirectories based on the first two hexadecimal characters of their object hash ID.  The hash distribution is assumed to be uniform, so if there are 26 objects in `.git/objects/17`, there are probably also about 26 objects in each of the other 255 `.git/objects/XX` directories as well, so there are about 26 x 256 = 6656 loose objects.  If there are 27 loose objects in `17/`, there are probably about 27 x 256 = 6912 loose objects.  Estimating the number, by counting one subdirectory, is faster than computing the actual number by counting all subdirectories.  As usual, Git does the fast thing when it can get away with it, as in this case.

Answer (score 2):

They will remain. You can call [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) to clean them up. To find them, you can, for example, use `git reflog` and `git fsck`.

AFAIK, to delete them on GitHub, you have to contact the support ([see this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)).

Comment: I'm pretty sure both the `git` CLI client and GitHub website eventually call `git gc`, but it takes a long time for that to happen.